# Haskell pattern-matching of custom tree data-type to reduce duplicate code

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

So, I'm new to Haskell and I have this function which works in it's current state, but there is a lot of repetition in the code. This is for a school assigment so I can't change the data-type declaration or makeWeightedTree input/output.

I have a custom weighted tree structure (Wtree) and I need to make the input (an array of leafs, L) into an array of a single root-node by linking leafs (L) to branches (B) ([Wtree] -> [Wtree]). In order to do so, I'm currently pattern-matching each combination of the Wtree constructors, which creates a lot of repetition which I don't know how to get around in Haskell just yet.

Here is my custom data-type:

```
data Wtree = L Integer Char | B Integer Wtree Wtree deriving (Show)
```

And here is the function that I'm using:

```
makeWeightedTree :: [Wtree] -> [Wtree]
makeWeightedTree []  = []   -- No Leafs in input, Done                                      
makeWeightedTree [x] = [x]  -- Done

-- Wtree Leaf and Leaf
makeWeightedTree (t1@(L w1 _) : t2@(L w2 _) : xs)
    | w1 > w2   = makeWeightedTree $ sortBy sortNodes (t1:t2:xs)
    | otherwise = makeWeightedTree $ B (w1+w2) t1 t2 : xs 

-- Wtree Leaf and Branch
makeWeightedTree (t1@(L w1 _) : t2@(B w2 _ _) : xs)
    | w1 > w2   = makeWeightedTree $ sortBy sortNodes (t1:t2:xs)
    | otherwise = makeWeightedTree $ B (w1+w2) t1 t2 : xs 

-- Wtree Branch and Leaf
makeWeightedTree (t1@(B w1 _ _) : t2@(L w2 _) : xs)
    |  w1 > w2  = makeWeightedTree $ sortBy sortNodes (t1:t2:xs)
    | otherwise = makeWeightedTree $ B (w1+w2) t1 t2 : xs 

-- Wtree Branch and Branch 
makeWeightedTree (t1@(B w1 _ _) : t2@(B w2 _ _) : xs)
    |  w1 > w2  = makeWeightedTree $ sortBy sortNodes (t1:t2:xs)
    | otherwise = makeWeightedTree $ B (w1+w2) t1 t2 : xs
```

Is there any smart way to get around the repeating lines in the guards? I thought that a case-expression could work, but I'm not familiar with it so I have failed to do anything with that. Thankful for any help or tips!

**Edit: My solution**

Based on the feedback I think this was the most appropriate solution for me since I'm still not too familiar to Haskell or functional programming in general.

```
makeWeightedTree :: [Wtree] -> [Wtree]
makeWeightedTree []  = []      -- No Wtree(s), Done      
makeWeightedTree [t] = [t]     -- Done
makeWeightedTree t@(t1:t2:xs) 
    | w1 > w2   = makeWeightedTree $ sortBy sortNodes t
    | otherwise = makeWeightedTree $ B (w1+w2) t1 t2 : xs 
    where 
        w1 = getWeight t1
        w2 = getWeight t2

getWeight :: Wtree -> Integer
getWeight (L w _)    = w
getWeight (B w _ _ ) = w
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the main thing you care about is getting the weight of a `WTree`, so I suggest you abstract that out.  You could write a function like:

```hs
weightOfTree :: WTree -> Integer
weightOfTree = ... -- use pattern matching
```

Then, it looks like you can reduce these eight `makeWeightedTree` cases down to two:

```hs
makeWeightedTree (t1 : t2 : xs) = 
  if w1 > w2 then ... else ...
  where
    w1 = weightOfTree t1
    w2 = weightOfTree t2
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel like this was exactly what I was looking for. Easy to read and easy to understand!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @DDub's idea of making a helper function to extract the weight of an arbitrary tree, define a `Semigroup` instance for your type:

```
data Wtree = L Integer Char | B Integer Wtree Wtree deriving (Show)

weight :: Wtree -> Integer
weight (L w _) = w
weight (B w _ _) = w

instance Semigroup Wtree where
    t1 <> t2 = B (weight t1 + weight t2) t1 t2
```

Then `makeWeightedTree` is simply

```
makeWeightedTree :: [Wtree] -> [Wtree]
makeWeightedTree [] = []
makeWeightedTree xs = [sconcat (sortBy sortNodes xs)]
```

(This is slightly different your function, but it's not clear why it would matter if you sort the entire list once rather than only caring that the first two elements are locally sorted at each step.)

---

You also appear to be using `[]` where you could be using `Maybe`, since you are always reducing a non-empty list of `Wtree`s to a single `Wtree`.

```
makeWeightedTree :: [Wtree] -> Maybe Wtree
makeWeightedTree [] = Nothing
makeWeightedTree xs = Just $ sconcat (sortBy sortNodes xs)
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the help! I feel like this solution might be a bit too advanced for me right now, I still haven't looked into Monads, but I'm sure it can help others if anyone finds this question.

Comment: There's no monad here. A semigroup is just a formal way of saying you can combine two values of a type into a single value. `sconcat` is just repeated combination. For example, `sconcat [x,y,z] == x <> y <> z`. (The real definition is longer, as it has to take into account that `sconcat []` is undefined, but still use `[]` as the base case for recursion over a list.)

Comment: Isn't Maybe a Monad? That was what I was refering to anyway.

Comment: But you aren't *using* `Maybe`'s monad instance in any way. (It becomes an option when it comes time to use `makeWeightedTree`, but it's not an absolute requirement.)